# How to filter observations with whole number and its decimal points?

Tags: stata

I have a dataset with values for variable id, say, `id =[1 2 2.1 3 4 4.1 4.2 5 6 7 7.1 8]`. I need to drop observations which has decimal points and the observation with whole number before the decimal point (for example-2 and 2.1 both will be dropped). That means my expected outcome would be `id =[1 3 5 6 8]`.

Comment: Please give data in Stata-readable form. No doubt your examples would be valid code in some other language(s), but for Stata questions, do please follow advice in the Stata tag wiki.

Comment: Ok, Next time I will follow the rule. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input float id
  1
  2
2.1
  3
  4
4.1
4.2
  5
  6
  7
7.1
  8
end

gen ID = floor(id)

egen bad = total(id != ID), by(ID)

list 

     +----------------+
     |  id   ID   bad |
     |----------------|
  1. |   1    1     0 |
  2. |   2    2     1 |
  3. | 2.1    2     1 |
  4. |   3    3     0 |
  5. |   4    4     2 |
     |----------------|
  6. | 4.1    4     2 |
  7. | 4.2    4     2 |
  8. |   5    5     0 |
  9. |   6    6     0 |
 10. |   7    7     1 |
     |----------------|
 11. | 7.1    7     1 |
 12. |   8    8     0 |
     +----------------+

drop if bad

list id

     +----+
     | id |
     |----|
  1. |  1 |
  2. |  3 |
  3. |  5 |
  4. |  6 |
  5. |  8 |
     +----+
```